# $f$ integrable on $A \times B$, show subset of $A$ is negligible

Tags: integration, measure-theory

$A \subset \mathbb R^m$ and $B \subset \mathbb R^n$ are boxes, and $f$ is integrable in the riemann sense on $(A\times B)$.

We define $$A_1 =\left\{a \in A \left|\exists \int_{B}f(a,b)db\right.\right\} \subset A.$$

Show that $A \setminus A_1$ has zero volume.

Comment: I have a strong feeling this is related to Fubini's theorem. Something along the lines of $\int_{A \times B} f = \int_{A} \int_B f(a,b)dbda = \int_{A_1}\int_B f(a,b)dbda + \int_{A \setminus A_1}\int_B f(a,b)dbda$